# QGIS and Python - create line with multiple points in postgis

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, point, line

How can I create a line, with Python functions, with many points that are records in PostGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% what you are asking for, but why not creating the line in PostGIS first?

```
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.the_geom ORDER BY gps_time) As newgeom
FROM gps_points As gps
GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```

That will create a different line for each gps track and order them by time. I use that to create bus routes, ordered by stop sequence.

Really fast too.

(from: [http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.htm](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html))

Comment: Does not work, gives error in "order by"

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm not a PostGIS expert, I just happened to use that function 2-3 weeks ago, but it would help.

Comment: I used it to create line from shapes points from gtfs:
CREATE TABLE cit.ligne_tr AS

SELECT p.shape_id, ST_MakeLine(geom) As geom

FROM (SELECT * FROM cit.shapes ORDER BY shape_pt_sequence) p

GROUP BY p.shape_id;